# Spring exception translation isn't working with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, exception

My dao class `com.myapp.dao.hibernate.XyzDaoImpl` is annotated with `@Repository`

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoJpa implements UserDao {

...
    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) throws Exception{
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }
...
}
```

My `app-data.xml` is as follow:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
       <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
       <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
     <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
     <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="0" />
  </bean>


    <!-- JPA Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect"
        p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
    />

    <bean name="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect">
    </bean>

    <bean name="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- detect les @persistentContext in dao -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


     <!-- This will ensure that hibernate or jpa exceptions are automatically translated into
         Spring's generic DataAccessException hierarchy -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>


 <bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" />

    <!-- Transaction Config -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.dao.hibernate" />

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Now, in my jUnit test method, I deliberately insert a duplicate object and I got `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` instead of a spring exception.

```
@Test public void testSaveUser() {
        String login = "duplicateLogin";

        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin(login);
        user.setPasswd("pass");
        InformationBean rep = ms.saveUser(user);
        assertEquals(Constants.REPLY_403, rep);
        System.out.println("user was not saved "+user);     
}


@Service
public class MessagingService{
...

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public InformationBean saveUser(User user) {
    InformationBean info ;
    try {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
        info = Constants.REPLY_200;
    }catch(DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        logger.warn("login already used.");
        info = Constants.REPLY_403;
    }catch(ConstraintViolationException cve) {
        logger.warn("login already used.");
        info = Constants.REPLY_403;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Oups error",e);       
        info = Constants.REPLY_500;
    }

    return info;
}
...
}
```

Here is the complete stack trace

```
DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [com.myapp.service.MessagingService.saveUser]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@f6852d] for JPA transaction
DEBUG - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@79df82]
Hibernate: insert into User (email, login, passwd) values (?, ?, ?)
8928 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
8929 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Duplicate entry 'u123456789012' for key 2
ERROR - Oups error
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.myapp.model.User]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1174)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:674)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy32.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.dao.hibernate.UserDaoImpl.saveUser(UserDaoImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy34.saveUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.service.MessagingService.saveUser(MessagingService.java:237)
    at com.myapp.service.MessagingService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$48584635.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.myapp.service.MessagingService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4c0c06a9.saveUser(<generated>)
    at com.myapp.service.MessagingServiceTest.testSaveUser(MessagingServiceTest.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.myapp.model.User]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2836)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:668)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'u123456789012' for key 2
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2696)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2105)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2398)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2316)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2301)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 71 more
DEBUG - Initiating transaction commit
DEBUG - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@f6852d]
DEBUG - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@f6852d] after transaction
DEBUG - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

*EDIT1: After removing the throws Exception from the saveUser() DAO method, it seems that Spring exception translation is working. My service method catchs DataIntegrityViolationException and return normally. However, the test method doesn't get the return but instead get an exception: TransactionSystemException. How can I avoid such unwanted exception that breaks everything?*

*Edit2: 
Spring exception translation was working fine, the problem comes from JPA/EntityManager.
See the complete story and how I managed to solve it: http://tinyurl.com/439dmul*

Comment: That's weird since `PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor` is invoked, but for some reason it does not translate your `PersistenceException`. Are you sure `com.myapp.dao.hibernate.UserDaoImpl` is annotated properly with `@Repository` and that `UserDaoImpl.saveUser()` does not declare any exceptions in the signature?

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz thanks. My UserDaoImpl.saveUser() declare exceptions in signature. I removed it and now my test fails with org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly. Why my service Method didn't catch the exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your latter question about `TransactionSystemException`: this exception was thrown when exiting `@Transactional` method in order to indicate that transaction had been rolled back.

If you want to reliably catch constraint violations, you need to do it around transaction, not inside it. For example, by using programmatic transaction demarcation inside `saveUser()` method instead of `@Transactional`, or by adding `try-catch` clause to the top-level method.

Comment: thanks @axtavt but why this behavior? two days ago I was using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() and it was working flawlessly. Now that I moved to full JPA using entityManager it breaks? Moreover, TransactionSystemException doesn't tell much about the problem compared to DataIntegrityViolationException or ConstraintViolationException

Comment: @redsonic: Not sure about difference between plain Hibernate and JPA behaviour. However, note that if you don't catch exception inside a transaction, it's thrown as is, without `TransactionSystemException`, so you can determine the cause.

Comment: it seems that DataIntegrityViolationException is catched in my service class and info = Constants.REPLY_403; is being executed and return normally, but somehow, in the test method, I don't get the return (rep is null) but instead I catch this exception TransactionSystemException

Comment: About receiving these exceptions "within" the transaction, this can be achieved if the entity manager is eagerly flushed, where there is a possibility of receiving these errors. e.g. when persisting an entity, entity manager can be manually flushed using entityManager.flush. Beware that flushing entity manager multiple times within a transaction is not very optimal, but surely gives more granular error handling.